# This function return me undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
var prizes = ['Un unicorno!', 'Un abbraccio!', 'Un gelato!'];
for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length; btnNum++) {
  document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function() {
    alert(prizes[btnNum]);
  };
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>
```

Why when i click return me undefined ? And how i can correct ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: TLDR; you need `let btnNum = 0`. But I do recommend you to read the linked question.